# proper Trim function

Tags: php, jquery, trim

Ok, I am a total newbie and cannot figure out where to place the trim function on a code that a developer created for a client. The current form places "\" before any apostrophe and I have googled solutions and tried placing functions in the file but everything I do breaks the client's form. Any help is appreciated.

The current structure is:

```
$dd_description =   $_POST['dd_description'];
```

and the review page of the form is:

```
Description:<strong> '. $dd_description .'</strong><br />
```

I just cannot seem where to place the 'trim'

Comment: Unsure exactly how you mean but you could try something like `str_replace('\', '', $dd_description)` to remove the `\`. Sounds like it's been passed through a function that escapes output. You should probably be careful how you remove them so you're not directly printing user input out to your page though as that can lead to XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: This was developed by another person for a client. I am now in a role that is slightly over my head, but I will look into this to see if you are onto something with vulnerabilities. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just allowing unparsed POST variables to appear on a users webpage is NOT recommended for security reasons.

Have you tried adding stripslashes() to the code?

```
Description:<strong> '. stripslashes($dd_description) .'</strong><br />
```

I'd recommend securing the input data further, perhaps wrap strip_tags around it also at least.

Comment: Thanks. Again, so simple. I had tried a global striplashes function, but it was not working. There are not too many fields to append this too and it works just fine. I knew it had to be a simple fix, but I am still new to the subtle changes and kept overcomplicating it with unnecessary quotes and parenthesis.

Comment: Okay, It might be worth doing something like this in such a case.


[code]
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
$_POST[($key)] = stripslashes($val);
}
[/code]

Comment: I had tried that before but it did not work. I most likely did not place the function in the right spot. As for the "NOT recommended" comment, I know this form was built by a developer for the client. I am now taking over but am not as qualified. I will certainly look into this to assure there is not any sort of problem with the way it was originally built. It is happening all through a functions.php file behind the scenes.

Comment: That's cool, sorry if it caused offence, just looking to help out :)

I'm sure that by placing the code inside the right are you'll get around it.

use a bit of googling for PHP security tips. php.net is a great resource also. Best of luck with the project :)

Answer (score 0):

Auto escaping apostrophes suggests that [Magic Quotes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is on. [Here's how to disable Magic Quotes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Magic Quotes may be protecting your SQL queries from SQL Injection, so proper investigation as to why it is on is required. If this is the case then it is recommended to convert the code to prepared statements, which don't require any string processing for SQL Injection.